# How do I Pass img.id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've got the following code which sets an image using HTML. When you click the thumbnail it displays a larger image below, all works great

While this works great, the issue I have is with portrait photos I want to set the width in my CSS to `width: 50%`;

If the photo is landscape call "expandedImg" otherwise call "smallerImg", have tried various ways to set the `<img id="expandedImg">` or "smallerImg" and use the `set.attribute`

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg")
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#expandedImg {
  margin-left: 7%;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="fivecolumn">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpg" alt="lnd1" style="width: 95%" height="95" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not a task for an id but a class for which you can use `classList`. Also, take a look at `figure` and `figcaption` tag.

Comment: Where is your `smallerImg` js and css codes?